# How to add a custom legend along with default legends

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have some lines plotted that has labels defined

```
plt.axvline(..., label='some text')
plt.legend()
```

But, I would like to add some custom legends other than the ones we have.
I know how to do it using `from matplotlib.patches import Patch` for color patches or `from matplotlib.lines import Line2D` for lines by code like

```
legend_elements = [Line2D([0], [0], color='b', lw=4, label='Line'),
                   Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='w', label='Scatter',
                          markerfacecolor='g', markersize=15),
                   Patch(facecolor='orange', edgecolor='r',
                         label='Color Patch')]

plt.legend(handles=legend_elements)
```

But the problem is that, the newer `plt.legend()` function overwrites the older legend that was plotted by default. I would like to have both, the default one, along with my custom defined legends.

I was looking for websites that can guide me on this, but I could find mostly on how to add custom legend, but not adding it along with the default legend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example, you can get the older legend then combine it with your legend:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

t = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
sig1 = np.cos(t)
sig2 = np.sin(t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, sig1, label='Sig 1')
ax.plot(t, sig2, label='Sig 2')
plt.legend()

old_handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

legend_elements = [Line2D([0], [0], color='b', lw=4, label='Line'),
                   Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='w', label='Scatter',
                          markerfacecolor='g', markersize=15),
                   Patch(facecolor='orange', edgecolor='r',
                         label='Color Patch')]


plt.legend(handles=old_handles + legend_elements)
```

[image]